# How to check if a Simple HTML element does not exist?

Tags: php, domparser

SimpleHtmldom can be used to extract the contents of the first element with class **a[itemprop="item"]**

```
$html = str_get_html($html); 
$item = $html->find('a[itemprop="item"]', 1)->innertext;
```

However if this class does not exist, PHP will throw an error

> Trying to get property of non-object

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the element exists first:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = str_get_html($html);

if (($html->find('a[itemprop="item"]', 1))) {
$item = $html->find('a[itemprop="item"]', 1)->innertext; 
}else{
$item = "element not exist";
}
```